# Is there a way do dynamically set ROWS BETWEEN X PRECENDING AND CURRENT ROW?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i'm looking for a way to, on my query, dynamically set the beginning of the window function on Sql Server using ROWS BETWEEN.

Something like:

```
SUM(field) OVER(ORDER BY field2 ROWS BETWEEN field3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

**field3** holds the amount of items (via group by from a CTE) that represent a group.

Is that possible or should i try a different approach?

**>> EDIT**

My query is too big and messy to share here, but let me try to explain what i need. It's from a report builder which allows users to create custom formulas, like "emplyoees/10". This also allows the user to simply input a formula like "12" and i need to calculate subtotals and the grand total for them. When using a field, like "employees", everything works fine. But for constant values i can't sum the values without rewriting a lot of stuff (which i'm trying to avoid).

So, consider a CTE called "aggregator" and the following query:

```
SELECT
    *,
    "employees"/10 as "ten_percent"
    12 as "twelve"
FROM aggregator
```

This query returns this output:

```
row_type    counter     company_name    department_name     employees   ten_percent     twelve
data        1           A               A1                  10          1               12
data        1           A               A2                  15          1,5             12
data        1           A               A3                  10          1               12
subtotal    3           A                                   35          3,5             12
data        1           B               B1                  10          1               12
subtotal    1           B                                   10          1               12
total       4                                               45          4,5             12
```

As you can see, the values fot "twelve" are wrong for subtotal and total row types. I'm trying to solve this without changing the CTE.

ROLLUP won't work because i already have the sum for other columns.

I tried this (i ommited "row_type_sort" on the table above, it defines the sorting):

```
CASE
    WHEN row_type = 'data' THEN
        MAX(aggregator.[twelve])
    ELSE
        SUM(SUM(aggregator.[twelve]))
            OVER (ORDER BY "row_type_sort" ROWS BETWEEN unbounded PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
    END AS "twelve"
```

This would work OK if i could change "unbounded" by the value of column "counter", which was my original question.

LAG/LEAD wasn't helpful neither.

I'm out of ideas. Is it possible to achieve what i need only by changing this part of the query, or the result of the CTE should be changed as well?

Thanks

Comment: You would have to use dynamic sql for that.

Comment: Obviously, SQL Server doesn't support this syntax (I'm guessing that you have already tried).  You should ask a question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to accomplish.

Comment: Is [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) something that might work for you? "Accesses data from a previous (LAG)/subsequent (LEAD) row in the same result set without the use of a self-join starting with SQL Server 2012 (11.x)."

Comment: would `select ..., 12 * counter as "twelve" from ...` solve your problem?

Comment: For this simple formula yes, but for complex expressions using multiplication, division and grouping numbers by parenthesis no, it would scale the result in a wrong way.

Comment: Also, please note that "ten_percent" is also a formula, and i can't multiply it by counter. I'm looking for a generic way to sum previous rows.

Comment: Is there any other answers for this question I to am wanting a solution for this question? I want to use a joined in value as my X in: `ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND X FOLLOWING`